# AngularJS return two http get requests but only first one is resolved

Tags: angularjs, json

I am new to angularjs.I am trying to create a mobile app using angularjs. Here only `if` condition is working and `else` is not working which means first `http` is working perfect while second is not working. How to solve this?

**app.js**

```
$http({method: 'JSONP', url: 'http://js/english.js?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'}).
    then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $scope.templeEn = response.data;
    });

$http({method: 'JSONP', url: 'http://js/malayalam.js?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'}).
    then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $scope.templeMl = response.data;
    });  


$scope.loadlanguages=function(files) {
    console.log(files);
    if(files=='english') {
        console.log('hai');
        $scope.result=$scope.templeEn;
        console.log( $scope.result);    
    }
    else {
        console.log('ml');
        $scope.result=$scope.templeMl;
        console.log( $scope.result)
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<button class="button button-icon" ng-click="loadlanguages('english')" >
    en
</button>

<button class="button button-icon" ng-click="loadlanguages('malayalam')" >
    ml
</button>
```

Comment: it looks like everything should be working fine. I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYACX/315/) similar to this for you to cross check your code.

Comment: Your code is perfectly working with your url.but when I pass my url on your code its not working.still shows the same error only first one is working yet @mJunaidSalaat

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat I didnt chane anything on your code simply change the url.but not working. if I pass english.js on first http it's working and malayalam.js is not working.and if I pass malayalam.js on first http its working and english.js not working

Comment: yes it won't work because the `url` you are trying does not return anything.  you should double check your `url` if it is correct or not.

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat thats not my url.I just example here .My exact url's  are http://www.obidostech.com/english.js and http://www.obidostech.com/malayalam.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/hYACX/316/) for your code and your `url`. This should work now.

please note that the fiddle would not be allowed access to your site and will throw a `cross-domain` error. I've used a [**chrome extension**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) to disable it and bring your data in the fiddle. below is the updated code and your response image.

```
$http.get("http://www.obidostech.com/english.js")
      .then(function(json) {
        $scope.responseFoo = json.data;
      },function(err){
        console.log(err)
      });

    $http.get("http://www.obidostech.com/malayalam.js")
      .success(function(json) {
        $scope.responseBar = json;
      },function(err){
        console.log(err)
      });

    $scope.response = [];

    $scope.loadlanguages = function(lang){
        if(lang === 'foo'){
            $scope.response = $scope.responseFoo
      }
      else{
        $scope.response = $scope.responseBar;
      }
    };
```

[image]

Hope it helps.